# Using 'end' as column name in Ruby on Rails (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I had an model with an "end" column (datetime format), only to discover that Heroku crashes and burns with illogical Active Record errors whenever I attempted to reference the column in a query.  I spent two hours trying to debug the extremely simple query, after which point I renamed the column to "end_at" and all of my problems disappeared.

Has anybody else experienced this issue? I'm curious of the reasoning behind this and hope that we can help others avoid the same mistake. A similar question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259020/using-end-as-column-name), but a clear answer was not presented.

Comment: what "illogical" errors were you getting? Also, you seemed to have answered your own question (by renaming the column) - is the question you are asking "Has anybody else experienced this issue?"

Comment: @Brett Yes, I figured out the problem, but I am more interested in the cause at this point.  I am wondering why a column named "end" results in such errors.  The error was `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"`, which was illogical because my syntax was correct.

Comment: In php would you try and name a variable or column `<?` or `array_walk`?  It seems perfectly obvious to me why you would want to avoid naming a class `class` or a module `module` or `Kernel::`.

Also, PGError means that the Postgres database threw an error which Rails is re-throwing so you can deal with it. The "illogical" ActiveRecord error you got is, in reality, a syntax error in your SQL because you named a column a reserved word (most likely) or constructed your query incorrectly (unlikely but possible).

Comment: @Brett Bender, Valid points (and I would never do that on a database-first design), but shouldn't ActiveRecord quote identifiers when it generates the SQL?  When I code-generate against SQL Server I defensively use [] for precisely that purpose (who knows if someone named a column with a space or odd character)

Comment: @Cade Roux No idea why activerecord isn't quoting its sql output, the original asker didn't post any code at all, so all we can do is speculate.  It's possible the queries are all hand-written and the original developer mistakenly forgot to quote the column because their last database didn't care. It's also possible it's really ActiveRecord's fault (though I bet less likely than developer error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BEGIN and END are reserved words in Oracle and SQL Server, but not sure why MySQL [doesn't consider them as such](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

However that PGError would appear to indicate that the database engine itself (and not any Ruby-related runtime) has indeed rejected the query because of the "end".

Reserved words (and names containing spaces) can be used if quoted - perhaps Active Record didn't quote the identifiers in the SQL which was generated.

I would look at the log in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) and see the statements generated.

And since the PGError means PostGreSQL and you mentioned Heroku (PostgreSQL 8.3) - I think this is because END is indeed a reserved word in PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/sql_reserved_words_checker/?word=end

Comment: true. what is inconvenient is that it lets you create a table with that column name in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

PostgresQL (which Heroku uses) [reserves END as a keyword](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), so it is giving you a syntax error because your syntax is incorrect.

There are two options for fixing it:

If Heroku is breaking because ActiveRecord is not quoting column names, you can rewrite every query that uses that model to explicitly quote the "end" column so PostgresQL doesn't blow up.

Whether or not ActiveRecord quotes that column name by default, renaming the column something more descriptive (end_time, end_date, etc) and also not a reserved word in both the language you are writing the app in as well as a reserved word in the SQL engine you are using.