# meta_search with meta_where gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-search, meta-where

I'm using meta_search and meta_where gem.In my controller file:

```
@search = Project.where('end <= ?', Time.zone.now) 
@search = @search.search(params[:search])
```

When I run this code I have error in browser like this

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "end"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have an 'end' column on projects, which could mean that you either have a migration and forgot to run it with `rake db:migrate`, or need to make a migration to add that column. If the column name were end_date, you could do:

`rails g migration add_end_date_to_projects end_date:date`

Then run the migration.

EDIT: 'end' is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, so I think the column will need to be renamed.

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Comment: Ah, 'end' is a reserved word in PostgreSQL, so I think you'll need to rename that column to something else. I'd recommend 'end_date' or 'end_time' as that's more railsy. See also the first answer in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570783/using-end-as-column-name-in-ruby-on-rails-mysql